# installing a python package in virtual environment

Tags: python, package, virtualenv

I want to install quippy which is  supported by python2.7. I created a virtual environment:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 quippy_env
```

and activated it. I compilation looks fine and I got no errors. However, when I try to import quippy it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named quippy
```

I would appreciate  your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install quippy?

in your virtual env run

```
pip install quippy
```

Most of the time the NoModuleFound exception is due to not having the python package installed in your env.

Comment: thanks for your comment. no, I downloaded the file from github and compiled it using make config, make...

Answer (score 0):

maybe manually download the package and install it.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have already  downloaded it and installed it.